# What is the definition of a closed quasi-nilpotent operator in the norm sense?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

How is defined a closed quasi-nilpotent operator in the norm sense ?
I mean something like $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\lim }\left\Vert A^{n}\right\Vert ^{\frac{1%
}{n}}=0$ for a bounded quasi-nilpotent operator $A$.

Comment: An operator is called quasinilpotent if its spectrum is trivial, to say $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: This is the definition for a bounded operator. What is about a closed operator ?